# Yii2 Protect Assets and Folder

Tags: php, yii2

Building a multimedia upload for ShareX with Yii2. From the internet, I can tell Yii 1.1 had a folder for protected assets. I'm just curious how to keep various files (txt, img, zip) etc in a protected file and serve them via the framework.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you provide a link regarding the protected file?

Comment: I would like to serve files via Yii2, and prevent users (or non users) from simply going to @webroot/assets/files directory, where files are currently being stored. @robsch

Comment: Actually, the files in the assets folder are intended to be accessed by the browser, so they must be accessible. They get fetched with an URL. The server cannot distinguish between the calls (e.g. image called via an image tag or entered manually in the URL bar of the browser). Is your aim that a user has to be logged in, so that it can access those assets? Is it about uploaded files? Then you probably need a different approach.

Comment: I am attempting to make an application with similar qualities to something like dropbox - how are user files kept from free, unwarranted access? @robsch

Comment: disable directory listing via htaccess. It will hide files on the directory when go to "{baseUrl}/files/" but files will be accessible only by full path  "{baseUrl}/files/somefile.txt". Otherwice, if you want fully inaccessible files via browser, you should other methods like move directory to upper level of the file system and access via php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @user3410311

> disable directory listing via htaccess

As for serving images securely, this resource helped a lot.

https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch15_09.htm